# corona sdk. Just starting with corona and lua and wondering about classes/instances

Tags: oop, class, lua, instantiation, coronasdk

I've just started learning corona and lua, my 1st project is to make a little dice game and Ive just started it! heres the dice object...

```
    --declare table + metatable

    local dice = {}

    local dice_mt = {__index = dice}


    --CONSTRUCTOR 

    function dice.new(ypos, xpos) 

    local newdice = {xpos = xpos, ypos = ypos,dicetext = display.newText("X", 50*xpos , 50*ypos , nil, 50)} 

    --dicetext = display.newText(facevalue, 50*xpos , 50*ypos , nil, 50)

    return setmetatable(newdice, dice_mt) 
    end

    --rolldice function

    function dice:rolldice()

    self.dicetext.text = math.random(0,6) 

    end

    return dice
```

the game is to have a grid of 25 dice which can be rolled (with rolldice function above)
Heres my main.lua

```
    display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

    local diceclass = require ("dice")

    for i = 1, 5, 1 do

    local die = diceclass.new(i,i)

    i = i+1

    end

    die:rolldice()
```

I'm trying to generate the grid of dice programatically (atm I am just generating 5 dice(just text) in a diagonal line. Thats fine so far but my problem is running the rolldice function. It works when there is only 1 dice but not when there is more.
I'm guessing the problem is that I have all these instances of the class with the same name.. Is there a way to give them different names programmatically as I create them in my for loop? Or is there some better way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`local` variables are so named because they are *local* to the scope in which they are defined. `die` is defined within the `for` loop. Therefore, it stops existing once you leave the `for` loop.

If you want to create an array of `die` objects, you need to create an array which is accessible *outside* of the loop, then add the `die` objects to this array.

Also, `i = i+1` is counter-productive, since Lua knows how to increment loops itself. Also, it may lead to undefined behavior.